# Which types of decking are easiest to maintain?

Tags: deck

I live in Portland, OR. Rainy city.

I will be expanding the deck at my house and in the process, I'm thinking I might upgrade to something nicer than pressure treated doug fir.

I have a cousin that put in a Mahogany deck last year and it's really nice. The color and color variation really appeal to me. At the same time, my dentist told me about how he used IPE at his house and while it sounds like a pain to install, maintenance sounds to be a breeze, ie non-existent.

If I want a long lasting, deck, that requires minimal sealing and such while still looking nice, what do you recommend?

Comment: You might not have the same issues as we have in the Mid-Atlantic area with the composite/plastic decks, but from my experiences on other people's decks, if they're in full sun, they get *hot*, to the point I didn't really want to walk barefoot on it.  You might not have the same issues in your area, particularly if you're in a well-shaded area, and it sounds like you're willing to spend on exotic woods, but I thought I'd comment for anyone else who might be considering.

Answer (score 3):

If budget is not a concern, you could go mahogany or teak.

If budget is a concern, I happen to like the look of the faux-wood polymer decking "boards" such as the [PVC ones from Lowes](http://www.lowes.com/pl_Rot+Free_4294934154+4294815653_4294937087_). I'm sure there are several other brands/types, too.

Answer (score 2):

[Trex](http://www.trex.com/decking/composite.aspx) composite decking looks really nice (though I'm sure it's expensive), and basically maintenance free.

Answer (score 1):

I have been happy with the [walnut TimberTech Earthwood Composite Decking](http://www.timbertech.com/products/decking-planks/earthwood/default.aspx) on our screen porch.